# How to pass both parameter and datasource to rdlc report sametime

Tags: c#, asp.net, report, rdlc

```
    private void Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string sql = "[companyid]   ,[companyname] ,[Shopid]   ,[shopname],[shopaddress],[shopphone],[fax], [footermsg],[footermsg_ar] FROM [shop] Where id  = '1' ";
            DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sql);
            DataTable dt = DataAccess.GetDataTable(sql);
            ReportDataSource reportDSDetail = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);

            string sqli = "SELECT [logo] FROM [logo] Where id= '1' ";
            DataAccess.ExecuteSQL(sql);
            DataTable dts = DataAccess.GetDataTable(sql);
            string path = Application.StartupPath + @"\LOGO\";
            string imagePath = path + dts.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
            ReportParameter pImageUrl = new ReportParameter("pName", "file://" + imagePath, true);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath =path+@"Rep.rdlc";
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { pImageUrl });
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDSDetail);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception=" + ex);
        }
    }
```

In RDLC report I made a parameter named pName and connected with the image and configure an external. 
I need to get both parameter and data source in the report, I tried many ways but failed.
Please help me to solve this issue to get both parameters as well as a data source in RDLC report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly you need to go to `Report Data` and add **`Parameters`** like this

[image]

after Adding parameters **`Right Click on textbox`** in which you want to show that `parameters`--> `Click Expression` and add **`Expression`** like this

[image]

where `Showdt` is `parameter` name

and from `code behind` pass `data source` and `parameters` together like this

```
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();//pass Your Datasource
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("Showdt", "Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
//you can add multiple parameter like this
this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[]{p1}); 
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
 ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

[you can check this](http://dotnetknowledgebox.blogspot.com/2012/01/passing-parameters-to-rdlc.html)